# Locale-independent strtod implementation

Tags: c, string, locale

I have a library which needs to parse double numbers which always use a point '.' as decimal separator. Unfortunately for this case, strtod() respects the locale which might use a different separator and thus parsing can fail. I can't setlocale() - it isn't thread-safe. So I'm searching for a clean locale-independent strtod implementation now. I have found multiple implementations so far, but all of them look hacky or just like bad code.
Can someone recommend a well-tested, working, clean (ANSI) C implementation for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab some known implementation (that doesn't depend on `atof`), such as the one distributed with ruby:
[ruby_1_8/missing/strtod.c](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_8/missing/strtod.c).

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I've been searching for. A well-tested and clean implementation.

Comment: I am afraid this is not a correct implementation, it didn't care about rounding, which is a very important thing in string-double converting. please google "Correctly Rounded Decimal to Floating-Point Conversion" and have a look.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** The proposed implementation from ruby contains bugs.
I wouldn't mind the small difference pointed out by gavin, but if you try to parse something like "0.000000000000000000000000000000000000783475" you will get 0.0 instead of 7.834750e-37 (like the stock strtod() returns.)

Other solution:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "strtod_locale_independent.h"

extern "C" double strtod_locale_independent(const char* s)
{
     std::istringstream text( s );
     text.imbue(std::locale::classic());
     double result;
     text >> result;
     return result;
}
```

I don't know how fast this is, though.

Comment: This is about 5x slower than the builtin strtod, and doesn't give you the end pointer, which is needed when you're using it for parsing.

Comment: Yes you are right. But the point is not performance. It is locale-dependency. Therefore, `strtod()` cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

Following the answer above, I tried using the Ruby implementation at [ruby_1_8/missing/strtod.c](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_8/missing/strtod.c).  However, for some inputs this gives different answers to gcc's built-in parser and to strtod from stdlib.h, both on Mac and on Linux platforms:

```
char * endptr ;
double value1 = 1.15507e-173 ;
double value2 = strtod( "1.15507e-173", &endptr ) ;
double value3 = test_strtod( "1.15507e-173", &endptr ) ;
assert( sizeof( double ) == sizeof( unsigned long ) ) ;
printf( "value1 = %lg, 0x%lx.\n", value1, *(unsigned long*)( &value1 ) ) ;
printf( "value2 = %lg, 0x%lx.\n", value2, *(unsigned long*)( &value2 ) ) ;
printf( "value3 = %lg, 0x%lx.\n", value2, *(unsigned long*)( &value3 ) ) ;
assert( value1 == value2 ) ;
assert( value1 == value3 ) ;
```

which prints

```
value1 = 1.15507e-173, 0x1c06dace8bda0ee0.
value2 = 1.15507e-173, 0x1c06dace8bda0ee0.
value3 = 1.15507e-173, 0x1c06dace8bda0edf.
Assertion failed: (value1 == value3), function main, file main.c, line 16.
```

So my advice is to test the chosen implementation before use.

Answer (score 1):

There's also gdtoa available on netlib, BSD style license: http://www.netlib.org/fp/gdtoa.tgz

Comment: gdtoa converts double to string while the OP is looking for string to double conversion.

Comment: @vitaut it has implementations of both things in it, it's not just an implementation of `dtoa()`

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot change the locale because the application is multi-threaded, and because re-implementing `strtod` is a daunting task if you wish to get the precise behavior, here is a simple alternative that should work for most cases:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double my_strtod(const char *s, char **endp) {
    char buf[1024];
    char *p = strchr(s, '.');
    if (p == NULL || (size_t)(p - s) >= sizeof(buf)) {
        return strtod(s, endp);
    }
    struct lconv *lp = localeconv();
    *buf = '\0';
    strncat(buf, s, sizeof(buf) - 1);
    buf[p - s] = *lp->decimal_point;
    double v = strtod(buf, &p);
    if (endp) {
        *endp = s + (p - buf);
    }
    return v;
}
```

If `my_strtod()` is used on very long strings, it may be more efficient to analyse the initial portion of the argument string to determine how many characters to copy from it.

If you use `my_strtod()` on modifiable arrays used only in the current thread, you can just temporarily replace the first period `.` with a decimal-point character from the current locale:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double my_strtod(char *s, char **endp) {
    char *p = strchr(s, '.');
    if (p != NULL) {
        struct lconv *lp = localeconv();
        *p = *lp->decimal_point;
    }
    double v = strtod(buf, endp);
    if (p != NULL) {
        *p = '.';
    }
    return v;
}
```

Of course, this approach uses `strtod()` so it assumes that other concurrent threads do not mess with the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

While this is very late, it may provide some insights for future readers. Following the pattern of Florian Kusche's reply above, here is a exclusively "C" alternative that I have successfully tested on various flavors of Linux. One of the requirements of this solution is to temporarily override the user's system locale prior to executing `strtod()`.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _LOCALE_N_ 13

int category[_LOCALE_N_] =
  {
   LC_ALL           , //   All of the locale
   LC_ADDRESS       , //   Formatting of addresses and geography-related items (*)
   LC_COLLATE       , //   String collation
   LC_CTYPE         , //   Character classification
   LC_IDENTIFICATION, //   Metadata describing the locale (*)
   LC_MEASUREMENT   , //   Settings related to measurements (metric versus US customary) (*)
   LC_MESSAGES      , //   Localizable natural-language messages
   LC_MONETARY      , //   Formatting of monetary values
   LC_NAME          , //   Formatting of salutations for persons (*)
   LC_NUMERIC       , //   Formatting of nonmonetary numeric values
   LC_PAPER         , //   Settings related to the standard paper size (*)
   LC_TELEPHONE     , //   Formats to be used with telephone services (*)
   LC_TIME            //   Formatting of date and time values
  };

void _store_locale_info(char *vals[_LOCALE_N_])
{
  /* store the current locale information in an array of strings for future use */

  int i;

  for (i=0; i<_LOCALE_N_; i++)
  {
    char *loc_str = setlocale(category[i], "");
    int L = strlen(loc_str);
    vals[i] = calloc(L+1, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(vals[i], setlocale(category[i], ""), L+1);
  }
}

void _restore_locale_info(char *vals[_LOCALE_N_])
{
  /* restore the locale information from a previosly-populated array of strings */

  int i;

  for (i=0; i<_LOCALE_N_; i++)
  {
    if (vals[i])
    {
      setlocale(category[i], vals[i]);
      free(vals[i]);
    }
  }
}

double _strtod_c (const char *string, char **endPtr)
{
  /* Wrapper function for strtod() that enforces the "C" locale before converting a floating-point
   * number from an ASCII decimal representation to internal double-precision format. */

  char *vals[_LOCALE_N_];
  double rval = 0;
  _store_locale_info(vals);
  rval = strtod(string, endPtr);
  _restore_locale_info(vals);
  return rval;
}

int main()
{
  char *str = "1024.123456";
  char **endPtr;
  char locale_str[100];

  printf("\nstr = \"%s\"\n\n", str);
  printf("Locale\n", str);

  strcpy(locale_str, setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"));
  printf("%-6s :: strtod(str, endPtr) = %.15g\n", locale_str, strtod(str, endPtr));

  strcpy(locale_str, setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE"));
  printf("%-6s :: strtod(str, endPtr) = %.15g\n", locale_str, strtod(str, endPtr));

  printf("---\n");

  strcpy(locale_str, setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"));
  printf("%-6s :: _strtod_c(str, endPtr) = %.15g\n", locale_str, _strtod_c(str, endPtr));

  strcpy(locale_str, setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE"));
  printf("%-6s :: _strtod_c(str, endPtr) = %.15g\n", locale_str, _strtod_c(str, endPtr));

  printf("\n");
}
```

The expected output on a compatible Linux installation is

```
str = "1024.123456"

Locale
C      :: strtod(str, endPtr) = 1024.123456
de_DE  :: strtod(str, endPtr) = 1024
---
C      :: _strtod_c(str, endPtr) = 1024.123456
de_DE  :: _strtod_c(str, endPtr) = 1024.123456
```

Comment: The OP explicitly wrote: *I can't setlocale() - it isn't thread-safe*.  If the function is used in a multi-threaded application, changing the locale as you do here above, may adversely impact other threads that rely on the current locale.