# Correct strtod implementation?

Tags: c, floating-point, strtod

Simple question: what is the correct bit-representation of the number 1.15507e-173, in double precision?
Full question: how does one determine the correct parsing of this number?

Background: my question follows from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994658/locale-independent-strtod-implementation/6924728#6924728) which shows two different bit-representations from three different parsers, namely

```
0x1c06dace8bda0ee0
```

and

```
0x1c06dace8bda0edf
```

and I'm wondering which parser has got it right.

**Update** Section 6.4.4.2 of [the C99 specification](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says that for the C parser,

```
"...the result is either the nearest representable value, or the larger
or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest
representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner."
```

This implies that the parsed number need not be the nearest, nor even one of the two adjacent representable numbers.  The same spec in 7.20.1.3 says that strtod() behaves essentially the same way as the built-in parser.  Thanks to the answerers who pointed this out.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499329/strtod-and-sprintf-inconsistency-under-gcc-and-msvc/2499570#2499570) to a similar question, and [this blog](http://www.exploringbinary.com/topics/#correctly-rounded-decimal-to-floating-point).

Comment: What does the C parser say? GCC 4.6 uses MPFR internally I believe, so I'd expect the result to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: There is no "correct" - I assume without checking that both of those answers are within one ULP of the mathematically exact value of `1.15507e-173`, since they're only 1 ULP apart. The C standard doesn't say which one the implementation must produce. IEEE 754 defines rounding modes, but I don't know whether it says anything about how they affect `strtod`.

Comment: Why this particular number anyway? Is that the one related to some recent bug?

Comment: @Steve, note 305 seems to imply that pragma STDC FENC_ACCESS influences strtod.

Comment: @Kerrek, the number has no particular significance; it's just one that I found that shows a discrepancy.  The C parser gives the first value, as does my system's strtod().

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the comment.  Is it that my number is equidistant between two representable ones, and the two implementations are rounding in different ways?

Comment: @Gavin: It's not exactly equidistant, because its binary decimal representation doesn't terminate. `strtod` says that the value is interpreted as a floating-point constant would be. 6.4.4.2/3 of C99 says "either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-deﬁned manner". So that's how much inaccuracy is tolerated, it's possible they're both correct even if (as Artefacto says), they're both the same side of the true value.

Comment: I see two 32 bit representations. Are you sure they are doubles?

Answer (score 1):

```
:= num1 = ImportString["\.1c\.06\.da\.ce\.8b\.da\.0e\.e0", "Real64", ByteOrdering->1] // First;
:= num2 = ImportString["\.1c\.06\.da\.ce\.8b\.da\.0e\.df", "Real64", ByteOrdering->1] // First;
:= SetPrecision[num1, Infinity]-numOr //N
:= numOr =  SetPrecision[1.15507, Infinity] * 10^-173;
             -190
= -6.65645 10
:= SetPrecision[num2, Infinity]-numOr //N
             -189
= -2.46118 10
```

Given that both deviate for the same side, it follows that the correct representation is the first one.

Comment: @Gavin There's no much to it, it reads the ieee 754 representation of the doubles, [converts them to infinite precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html) numbers and then checks how far they are from your target.